# Tiny clickable area in Firefox

Tags: css, html-lists, hyperlink, footer

In Firefox, the clickable area of the links in my footer is TINY. The clickable area does not span the entire label - both in terms of width and height. In IE, it's fine. Any ideas?

Here is my footer code:

```
<div id="footer">
<ul>
<li>RKM Research and Communications, Inc.&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
<li>1039 Islington St&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
<li>Portsmouth, NH  03801&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
<li>603.433.3982&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
<li><a href="mailto:info@rkm-research.com">email us</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="copyright">
<li>&copy; 2012 RKM Research and Communications, Inc.   </li>
<li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy policy</a> </li>
<li><a href="terms.html">Terms of use</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my CSS:

```
div#footer ul li{
color : #036;
background-color : transparent;
display: inline
}

div#footer ul li a{
color : #115EAC;
text-decoration : none;
display:inline-block;
paddding:10px 20px;
}

.footer ul li a:hover{color:#F6901E;
text-decoration : underline;
}
```

I've even tried to apply a block style using a class, but it still did not help:

```
<li class="flink"><a href="mailto:info@rkm-research.com">email us</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.flink ul li a{
color : #115EAC;
text-decoration : none;
display:block;
paddding:10px 20px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example through jsfiddle or any other service (even self hosted). But please, only provide test code. Anyway, did you look through firebug whether the display is overwritten or not?

Answer (score 0):

Small world, I also live in Portsmouth.

With the code you provided, the clickable area is just as it should be. You can verify this here: http://jsfiddle.net/cCDaL/1/

I've made the background of each `a` element yellow, so you can see exactly what the clickable area is, and it is indeed what it should be.

I think the answer to your problem is that you have another CSS rule that is making the clickable area tiny, possibly `line-height` or `padding` (padding is not clickable in links). You can use the Chrome or Firefox inspectors to see what could be the problem here.

**Another edit:** In Firefox Aurora 14.0a2, the clickable area is indeed also normal, for me, on your website http://www.rkm-research.com/. Here's a screenshot with the Firefox inspector:
[image]